# Jquery convert dropdown to select with onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert a drop down

```
<ul class="cat-items selectdropdown">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-25">
        <a href="http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/?product_cat=a1-compressor" title="View all posts filed under A-1 Compressor">A-1 Compressor</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-207">
        <a href="http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/?product_cat=world-hand-dryer" title="View all posts filed under World Hand Dryer">World Hand Dryer</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To select menu dynamically. Here is what I am using and it looks perfectly. But The conversion is not being made and drop down is displayed instead of select.Here is jquery code which loads on ready.

```
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function() {
        var list = $(this),
            select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
            $(select).attr("style","cursor:pointer;display: inline-block; width:99%;");
        $('>li', this).each(function() {
            var ahref = $(this).children('a'),
                target = ahref.attr('target'),
                option = $(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(ahref.attr('href')).html(ahref.html());

        });
    });
```

Once select is displayed I will use onchange to make it work.

```
$('select').bind('change',function () {
   //Redirect Page
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Here id demo url:[restaurantapplianceparts.com](http://restaurantapplianceparts.com)
Ahmar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your code with some changes to get this to work.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="cat-items selectdropdown">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-25">
        <a href="http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/?product_cat=a1-compressor" title="View all posts filed under A-1 Compressor">A-1 Compressor</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-207">
        <a href="http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/?product_cat=world-hand-dryer" title="View all posts filed under World Hand Dryer">World Hand Dryer</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$('ul.selectdropdown').each(function() {
        var list = $(this),
            select = $(document.createElement('select')).insertBefore($(this).hide());
            $(select).attr("style","cursor:pointer;display: inline-block; width:99%;");
        $('>li', this).each(function() {
            var ahref = $(this).children('a'),
                target = ahref.attr('target'),
                option = $(document.createElement('option')).appendTo(select).val(ahref.attr('href')).html(ahref.html());

        });
    $(select).change(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    });
    });
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cf7Pt/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine in jsfiddle. i updated your code.

```
<div id="dropdown">
<ul class="cat-items selectdropdown">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-25">
        <a href="http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/?product_cat=a1-compressor" title="View all posts filed under A-1 Compressor">A-1 Compressor</a>
    </li>
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-207">
        <a href="http://restaurantapplianceparts.com/?product_cat=world-hand-dryer" title="View all posts filed under World Hand Dryer">World Hand Dryer</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
 createSelectBox();
 function createSelectBox() {
    var select = $('<select>');
    $('ul.selectdropdown li').each(function() {
       var anchor = $(this).find('a')
       var option = $('<option>');
       option.val(anchor.attr('href')).text(anchor.text());
       select.append(option);
   });
   $('#dropdown').html(select);
 }
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/mannejkumar/pVuxR/)

Answer (score 0):

`.live` is deprecated since.. I don't even remember.
use `.on`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

also take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/ and use it's dropdown script.

don't reinvent the wheel.

creating a select menu for navigation is also bad practice.

Comment: Problem is not with live I am not even using onchange yet. Select is not being displayed. That is the problem. I said once it is displayed THEN I will use onchange.